# How to scale proportionally

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, extrude

[image: GIF animation]

I'm extruding the faces selected on the screenshot.
With the selection active I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (region vertex normal). the result that I'm getting is shown in the animaiton above. The extrude isn't done proportionally at the sides and height or z-axis.
May I know the reason what I'm doing wrong and how to make it extrude all the sides proportionally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you haven't applied scale , so to apply scale ,press space bar search for Apply Object Transform , click the option then go at the tool-bar then under the tool-shelf and select scale.
then repeat the steps you are doing in your question.
Note: you should be in object mode to be able to search for Apply Object Transform.

Comment: thats perfect..

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, then you just need to extrude then confirm the operation immediately before beginning any transform. 
<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>LMB</kbd> and then you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale along the normals.

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying u have understood my question correctly and showing correct what i need. but when im doing the same as u have done the question come same its not proportionally scaling whats the reason i dont understand plz do reply